# how to export an illustrator layers to photoshop but keep the layers as smart vector objects?

Tags: export, layer, adobe-illustrator, psd

I want to have the same layers i have in  illustrator, within photoshop, but not by copying and pasting - because when so i lose layer position and size -, or exporting to PSD -I lose the edibility in illustrator-. is there something else possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure if this will be exactly what you are looking for, but thought it might be helpful anyway.

If you're exporting each layer as an individual image file (.jpg .png etc.) one way to maintain the position of objects for reassembling the layers in Photoshop is to select the 'Use Artboards' option on the export screen (at the bottom left corner of the first screen you are presented with). Doing so, and maintaining the same resolution for each layer-image on the second menu screen you are presented with (where you can also select the empty space to be transparent - particularly useful for this re-assembling task!) means that, on opening each layer-image in Photoshop you can copy and paste the layers into the same document (I usually copy the others into one and 'Save As..' a new file as then I don't have to worry if I have the resolution and size settings right correct for a new document) safe in the knowledge that the default snap settings mean each layer will be arranged correctly in relation to the others.

While this is a bit arduous to begin with, assuming you maintain the separate layers in the Photoshop document, once this Photoshop assembly document is set up any changes you make only necessitate the exporting and copying in of the altered layer(s) from illustrator, rather than setting up an entirely new document.